# How to use docker (respectively docker-in-docker) to start an nginx over Gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I have a DigitalOcean server with a gitlab runner registered to a simple Gitlab repo. In a first step, I would like to just pull and run plain nginx. I can do this with the docker installation on that server without any problems.

So now I want to do this with the help of dind (docker-in-docker) as it is recommended by the gitlab documentation over a gitlab runner.

I defined the following gitlab-ci file:

```
image: docker:18.03.1-ce

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  script:
    - docker pull nginx
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

My gitlab runner is registered with the repo just fine. This is the config.toml of the gitlab-runner service:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "my-runner-04"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = TOKEN
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:18.03.1-ce"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

... the job gets done just fine. There are no errors in the console output of the gitlab page. This is the output:

```
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
84edac280a13714f3c5446ea024ad47864f68f6e5b73383427a28180227f37fd
Job succeeded
```

Now, if i visit the ip address of my server. The static nginx test page does not show up. So I suspect there is something wrong with the port exposure of dind or with the paths? What exactly am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to host website on nginx in GitLab CI?

GitLabCI is intended for testing/deployment. 
Your gitlab-ci file says:
download nginx + run nginx => end...

If you want to run nginx on your DigitalOcean server do it out of GitLabCI.

I can imagine your design for testing PHP aplication (in GitLabCI):

1. download PHP app...
2. pull and run nginx
3. try to download source code
   of PHP app via nginx/check response 200.. etc..

Comment: I am new to this and I am just starting to implement a CI/CD architecture. So this is my first test and I want to keep things simple. Of course I don't want to just run a nginx server. I want to run my node app. Anyway, I tried to containerize this plain nginx image in order to test the gitlab runner. But I don't really get why it does not work.